# Stop Deprecated warning in php

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

**I have some problem with Deprecated warning.**

I am making a php web application. I am using core php in my office, and I tried to use same code in my house bt Depricated warning makes me trouble. I know it can be removed using mysqli or PDO. But I use mysql method many times so I have to change it many times.

Here I am trying to ask is that can I use any method to disable the warning.

Comment: Then disable the warnings. But don't come back here when your code stops working altogether after the next system update.

Answer (score 0):

To disable warning to have to change the display errors level.

```
error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED );
```

This set disable Notices, Strict and deprecated warnings, but output others errors.

Anyway, please note that `mysql_` was permanently removed in PHP 7, so you have to migrate to `mysqli` or `PDO` to preserve compatibility code.

Disabling warnings you're just putting off a **to-do** action.